# TypeError: Error #1006: addEventListener is not a function

Tags: actionscript-3

New to flash, just trying to complete an assignment. 
A simple nav interface with start and end screens. I have that working. the code is simple.

Now I'm trying to insert [this](http://www.ilike2flash.com/2011/08/math-game-in-actionscript-3-part-1.html) tutorial into one of my frames/pages. 
at the moment I'm getting the error in the title, but anyway, here is the code.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.utils.setTimeout;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public class MathGameFinal extends MovieClip
    {
        private var buttonsArray:Array = new Array();
        private var num1Array:Array = new Array();
        private var num2Array:Array = new Array();
        private var answersArray:Array = new Array();
        private var count:uint = 0;
        private var numOfQuestions:uint = 20;
        private var numRange:uint = 20;
        private var startTime:uint;
        private var currentTime:uint;

        public function MathGameFinal()
        {
            // constructor code
            buttonsArray = new Array(oneBtn,twoBtn,threeBtn,fourBtn,
            fiveBtn,sixBtn,sevenBtn,eightBtn, nineBtn, zeroBtn, clearBtn);

            for (var i:uint = 0; i < buttonsArray.length; i++)
            {
                buttonsArray[i].buttonMode = true;
                buttonsArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked);
            }

            mgEnd_Screen.visible = false;

            mgStart_Screen.mgStart_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
        }

        private function startGame(e:MouseEvent):void{
            mgStart_Screen.visible = false; 
            init();
        }

        private function init():void { 
            startTime = getTimer();
            currentTime = 0;

            for(var j:uint = 0;  j < numOfQuestions; j++){
                num1Array.push( uint(Math.random() * numRange)+1 );
                num2Array.push( uint(Math.random() * numRange)+1 );
                answersArray.push( num1Array[j] + num2Array[j] );
            }
            Input_Txt.text = num1Array[count] + ' + ' + num2Array[count];  
        }

        private function buttonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
            switch(e.target){
             case zeroBtn: Output_Txt.appendText('0'); break;
             case oneBtn:   Output_Txt.appendText('1'); break;
             case twoBtn:  Output_Txt.appendText('2'); break;
             case threeBtn:  Output_Txt.appendText('3'); break;
             case fourBtn:  Output_Txt.appendText('4'); break;
             case fiveBtn:  Output_Txt.appendText('5'); break;
             case sixBtn:  Output_Txt.appendText('6'); break;
             case sevenBtn: Output_Txt.appendText('7'); break;
             case eightBtn:  Output_Txt.appendText('8'); break;
             case nineBtn:  Output_Txt.appendText('9'); break;
             case clearBtn:  Output_Txt.text ='';     break;
            }
            setTimeout(checkResult,400);
        }
        private function checkResult():void{
            if(Output_Txt.text == answersArray[count]){
            Output_Txt.text = ''};
            count++;
            Input_Txt.text = num1Array[count] + ' + ' + num2Array[count];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of object are `oneBtn` and others? Also, you might do `import flash.display.*` instead of importing just `MovieClip` in case these objects are not `MovieClip`s.

Comment: oneBtn and others are buttons, I just changed it to import flash.display.*
I didn't get any noticeable change.

Comment: What buttons? A button can be a `SimpleButton`, a `MovieClip`, a `Sprite` or a totally custom object. Especially if your object is a wrapper over a MC, which does not descend from `InteractiveObject`, but uses the embedded MC to capture mouse clicks, this way it won't have `addEventListener` as its own method.

Comment: I made the buttons by inserting new symbols and selecting the button option, instead of movieclip from the drop down menu.

Comment: Then they are `SimpleButton`s. Hmm. Then, check if either of them is undefined. `if (buttonsArray[i] == undefined) trace(i, "undefined")` Also, check if the error refers to `mgStart_Screen.mgStart_Btn` which too can be undefined. This is one of the drawbacks involved when working with a `MovieClip` - they are dynamic, so compiler cannot check if you made a typo on the properties, and instead they turn out `undefined` at runtime and cause various crap.

Comment: the buttonsarray check made the output become 
0 undefined

TypeError: Error #1006: addEventListener is not a function.
 at MathGameFinal()

Comment: This means that the element at index 0 (`oneBtn`) is undefined. Check the actual button instance name on the `MathGameFinal` library object. Note that these names are case sensitive.

Comment: Yep, one of the buttons was misnamed, now I'm getting this about line 29 though - TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at MathGameFinal()[D:\Intro to Multi\MathGameFinal.as:29]